# Sharing mood and emotions with Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create an app which allows users to share a message with their feelings included. Indeed, Facebook recently released a new feature to share feelings and emotions with emoticons.

Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CSap.png

However, there is no documentation about it.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Unfortunately the current API doesn't have any `call` or documentation for that